# BigQuery - Modify scheduled query

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a query that runs every hour and dumps to bigquery table. This is working fine. However I can't see from the UI how to manually trigger this query, or edit the schedule. Clicking Scheduled Queries takes me to a wizard for creating a new scheduled query. Is this functionality available in the BigQuery web UI?

Comment: You should be able to see the Scheduled Query list in the UI (both the new and the old versions). Is your query a scheduled query?

Comment: It was a query that I wrote in the query editor in the new UI, tested and then clicked  Scheduled Query -> Create new schedule query under the query editor and set it output/overwrite a table every hour.

Comment: Ah found it. The scheduled query was in a different project... Thanks ECris

Answer (score 11):

Go to the scheduled query, click on 'edit'.

Then edit your query.

Then click on "schedule query", which in this context has the option "update scheduled query".

[image]